# Babylon 10's "say it" feature not working in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, translation

[Babylon 10](http://www.babylon.com/translation_software)'s "say it" feature not working in windows 8. Babylon 10 is dictionary and transliteration software.

It has a feature called "say it" by which we can spell the words. You can access this feature by going to Menu → Settings → Sound.

You can see that the human voice is disabled or it's not working. Any solution?

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear.  Your first sentence needs to be more clear.  I suggest phrase it in another way

Comment: pleas somebody help me

Comment: @Ramhound: As far as I can tell, this is an SaaS solution available for Windows. The Mac version is separate. Related (on Reddit): http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/28s2kc/serious_in_tv_commercials_why_are_macs_used_more/

Comment: anyway i quit babylon .Use GoldenDict or Lingoes

Answer (score 0):

Babylon enforcing user to buy their human voices.In order to do this they have removed it's feature to use windows build in speech voices.So I recommend every one to switch to GoldenDict.